# $G$ is Abelian Group with neutral element $e$ and $aa =e \forall a \in G$ Show this function is bijective for all $a \in G: \tau_a: G \to G; x \to xa$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an Abelian Group with neutral element $e$ and $aa = e$   $\forall a \in G$

Show that this function is bijective for all $a \in G$:
$$\tau_a: G \to G; x \to xa$$

---

My attempt:
Bijective means both Injective and Surjective.

For Injective we have:

$$f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$$
$$x_1a = x_2a \implies x_1aa =x_2aa \implies x_1e = x_2e \implies x_1 = x_2$$

For surjective we have:
$$\forall y \in B, \exists x \in A: f(x) = y$$
$$x \cdot a = y$$
Choose $x = ya^{-1}$
$$x \cdot a = ya^{-1}a = y$$

---

Is this more or less correct ?

Comment: yes it's correct. Notice that $a^{-1}=a$, so just choose $x=ya$.

Comment: $\tau_a$ is bijective for *every* group $G$. In fact, you didn't use the abelianess and the use of the other assumption is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a group with $a\in G$. Then
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \rho_a: G&\to G\\
> g&\mapsto ga
> \end{align}$$
>
> is a bijection.

*Proof:* Suppose $g=h$. Then $\rho_a(g)=ga=ha=\rho_a(h)$, so $\rho_a$ is well-defined for arbitrary $a$.

Consider $\rho_{a^{-1}}$: we have, for $g\in G$,

$$\begin{align}
(\rho_a\circ\rho_{a^{-1}})(g)&=
\rho_a(\rho_{a^{-1}}(g))\\
&=\rho_a(ga^{-1})\\
&=(ga^{-1})a\\
&=g(a^{-1}a)\\
&=ge\\
&=g\\
&={\rm id}_G(g),
\end{align}$$

so $\rho_a\circ\rho_{a^{-1}}={\rm id}_G$; similarly, $\rho_{a^{-1}}\circ\rho_{a}={\rm id}_G$.

Hence $\rho_a$ is a bijection. $\square$

Here $\tau_a=\rho_a$.